# Require re-register MFA using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on the MVC application which is using Microsoft Azure Active Directory for signing in. I am also going to enable the MFA for users.
If the user changes the phone number or phone then that user needs to able to reset MFA from the application itself. I know we can reset MFA from the portal using **Require re-register MFA**.
[image]

Is there any way to accomplish this functionality using Graph API or using code?

Comment: If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

After a long time of searching and testing, I am sure that [Update phoneAuthenticationMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/phoneauthenticationmethod-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#examples) api can definitely meet your requirements.

[image]

[image]

Comment: But what if the user using the Microsoft Authenticator application?

Comment: @V.Mulik  I think we are talking about the same thing,  but I used the `Graph Explorer `tool to directly call the api. Of course, you can also grant `delegation permissions` or `application permissions` to the application, and then use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) or [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to obtain an access token , Then use the token to call this api to modify the MFA for the user.

Comment: @V.Mulik  I have provided the [api documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/phoneauthenticationmethod-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) to you, if you encounter problems in use, you can call me at any time :)

Comment: I tried this API but it is not working as expected. In my case users are going to use the [Authenticator APP for MFA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/multi-factor-authentication-setup-auth-app). The API just updates the phone number. If the user changes the phone (device) and wants to set up MFA in that new phone. Is that possible to using code?

Comment: I'm also trying to achieve the same thing. @V.Mulik did you find a solution?

Comment: I didn't found any solution using graph API. But I am using a different solution of using Azure Automation and MS flow combination. Triggering MS flow which runs the Automation Runbook containing Powershell script to reset MFA. 

Here is the Powershell script to reset MFA. - https://techwizard.cloud/2020/11/10/powershell-tip-office-365-invoke-re-register-mfa/

Comment: @V.Mulik Would this work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/microsoftauthenticatorauthenticationmethod-delete

Comment: In Microsoft Graph, deleting the authentication device will force the user to require registration (If your organization enforces this). But this isn't the same behavior employed by PowerShell MSOL module. Resetting MFA using MSOL leaves the registered devices, yet still forces the user reregister. 
I wished Microsoft had a Graph end point that mimics the MSOL implementation

Comment: @BDarley I have asked here, so we'll see what they say: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/15504

Comment: @BDarley It's still not supported. So upvote my feature request: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/microsoft-graph-add-support-for-quot-require-re-register-mfa/idi-p/3062110